# Order by each item

Tags: mysql, database, select, doctrine-orm

I have mysql table with columns 'item_id' and 'item_rank'. I want select all records from this table but i want get results ordered by rank each item so something like this:

```
item=1; rank=1
item=1; rank=2
item=2; rank=1
item=2; rank=2
```

I am working with doctrine (and this table is one entity without any relations) so if you get me hint directly in doctrine I will be glad.

Sorry I did not show up any my attempts but I don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: ...ORDER  BY item ASC, rank ASC... ?

Comment: Simpler than I thought :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to select a order by and then a secondary order. Something like this should work:

`ORDER BY item_id ASC, item_rank ASC`